# Minimum velocity of the particle at the highest point

Tags: rotational-kinematics

> A particle of mass *m* is fixed to one end of a light rod of length *l* and rotated in a vertical circular path about its other end. What is the minimum speed of the particle at the highest point?

It occurs to me that the answer should be zero. But I am not getting a strong conceptual reasoning behind it.
Can anyone please answer the question with proper explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand this motion, let us check first the case of a particle's motion in a vertical circle; here the particle of mass $m$ is attached to an inextensible string of length $R$ which provides the necessary centripetal force along with gravity.

Let the initial velocity be $u$ at the lowest point of the vertical circle. After time $dt$, it moves to some other point transversing angle $\theta$. The height at which it is now located is $$h = R(1 - \cos\theta)$$. Neglecting all non-conservative force, from work-kinetic energy theorem, we get the velocity at the point after $dt$ is $$v^2 = u^2 -2gh$$. The necessary centripetal force is $$T - mg\cos\theta = \dfrac{mv^2}{R}$$

The particle will complete the circle when at the highest point if the string doesn't slack at the highest point when $\theta = \pi$. There must be centripetal force to make this happen. To find the minimum centripetal force, we make $T = 0$ so that our new centripetal force is $$mg = \dfrac{mv^2}{R} \implies v= \sqrt{gR}$$ . Now this is the minimum velocity at the top which the particle must have in order to cover the whole circle. **Why?? Why in order to find the minimum centripetal force, I have made $T = 0$? Even if it is so, why doesn't the gravity bring down the particle as if it were a free-fall instead of acting as a centripetal force??** Because if there is velocity more than $\sqrt{gR}$, then only is tension required to provide the *extra* centripetal force for the *extra* velocity. Regarding free-fall, yes the particle would had a free-fall if it had zero velocity at the top; remember **if the velocity vector is perpendicular to the force which is pointing radially to some point, it is a *configuaration* of __circular-motion**.  Using $v_\text{min}^2 = u_\text{min}^2 -2gh \implies u_\text{min} = \sqrt{5gR} $

---

Now come to your case where in place of the string a light rod is placed; the constraint has been changed. Now we need not bother about whether the particle would fall when at the top. So, from  this point we can say the particle can have any velocity. It need not, thus, have the minimum initial velocity $\sqrt{5gR}$. It can have any velocity but **WARNING** the velocity ***CANNOT*** be equal to zero at the topmost point because if the velocity becomes zero, there would be no centripetal force to move the particle to complete the whole circle. But it can be very, very, very, close to zero ie, $v > 0$ but $v \approx 0$. To complete the case, I am adding the minimum initial velocity which we get from $$\dfrac{m(u^2 - v ^2)}{2} = mgh \implies u = 2\sqrt{gR}$$. So the minimum initial velocity must be infinitesimally larger than $2\sqrt{gR}$. The minimum velocity at the topmost point is thus *infinitesimally* greater than $0$.

*Note of Apology*: Yes, really sorry for writing some irrelevant stuffs but I deem it apt enough that in order to understand that the minimum topmost velocity cannot be $0$ in order to have centripetal force for covering the whole circle; here most of the texts baffle and write $v_\text{min} = 0$ at the topmost point but they forget that there must be centripetal force in order to transverse the whole circle & if the velocity is zero, from $\dfrac{mv^2}{R}$, we get the centripetal force also becomes $0$. However it can have the velocity at the top very, very, very close to zero as long as it doesn't nullify the centripetal force. Thus the minimum topmost-point velocity is just infinitesimally greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful. I kinda thought it this way but you gave the most proper explanation. Just another question, if the velocity of the topmost point was actually zero, then would the rod go still in the air? Or due to inertia of motion, it would complete the circle? Sorry for disturbing you again, but you really seem good in explaining. :)

Comment: @curiousbrain: Really pleased to help you. Regarding your query, let me start from the beginning of the journey. The rod is like a pendulum. When the particle has some tangential velocity that is perpendicular to the rod, it tries to move in that direction. Having moved infinitesimally, a component of gravitational force acts as centripetal force which compels it to transverse the circle. During the course of the trajectory, kinetic energy is converted to PE. If the particle was given initially only $2mgR$ KE, all of it will get converted to PE of the system at the topmost point..

Comment: .. & there it would become still; there is no centripetal force since there is no configuration I mentioned above necessary for circular motion. So, it will remain there along with the rod unless some external agent infinitesimally moves it from that point. It is a good question to ask about inertia of motion. Newton's First law can be applied during uniform motion, But that's not the problem.! We can think of infinitesimal time just before its ascent at the topmost point during which the velocity can be considered constant...